# Asynchronous , Async Await

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

I have list of sensor details and i need to get configuration setting for each sensor and apply some business logic. I want to do Aynchrosnously, like each sensor will call the same method and execute its logic at the same time.I tried with Async and await and below is sample. Please let me know, if the below will help to execute each sensor execute asynchronously.

```
public static async Task GetSensor()
        {
            List<SensorMaster> sensorAddress = GetSensorService();
            foreach (SensorMaster sensorInfo in sensorAddress)
            {
               await ParseSensor(sensorInfo);
            }
        }

private static async Task ParseSensor(SensorMaster senInfo)
        {

                List<Sensor> sTestdownTime = await GetTestDownTime(senInfo);
                if (DateTime.Parse(sTestdownTime[0].LastHeartBeatAt.ToString()).Year > 1900)
                {
                    CreateEvent(senInfo, sTestdownTime);
                }            


        }

public static async Task<List<Sensor>> GetTestDownTime(SensorMaster senInfo)
        {
            List<Sensor> lstSensor = new List<Sensor>();
            var connectionString = "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xx;persist security info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxx;";
            var asyncConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString) { AsynchronousProcessing = true }.ToString();

            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(asyncConnectionString))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SetingSp", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StationType", senInfo.SensorName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ThresholdValue", senInfo.SensorThreshold));
                using (SqlDataReader dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Sensor cpData = new Sensor();
                            cpData.SensorName = dr["SensorName"].ToString();
                            cpData.LastHeartBeatAt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["LastTimeStamp"]);
                            lstSensor.Add(cpData);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return lstSensor;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In `GetTestDownTime`, you should use all the asynchronous methods you can, e.g., `SqlConnection.OpenAsync` and `SqlDataReader.ReadAsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will execute asynchronously. But not in parallel. And I don't think you should even try to make it parallel unless you have a very clear performance problem.

Going parallel (with for example `Parallel.ForEach()`) would open many SqlConnections at once. Unclear on what kind of system you are running, and what would be expected.